# Is there a way to detect if an entity was saved during the current request after flush being called?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Currently have a controller listener that needs to know if an entity was saved on the current request or not.

Doesn't look like the unit of work details will help?

Comment: Why does UnitOfWOrk not help? If your entity is `STATE_DETACHED` it was persisted or not? What do you need that information for? Without knowing an details I would assume an EventListener would be the cleanest way to implement whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: What is a controller listener?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like dbrumann is right: more info would help, but at the moment you call `persist()` your entity is given it's auto-generated id value, so practically if an entity is persisted it will have an id, if not, for ex. you just created it and set some values but did not persist, it won't have an id. Hope it helps!